# How do I keep my current model in scope inside my method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, prawn

I have a Rails model and in one of the methods I am generating a pdf using prawn like so;

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  def pdf_output
    Prawn::Document.new do
      text "Start date: #{start_date.strftime('%e %b %Y').squish}"
    end
  end

end
```

In that text method I am trying to output the start_date attribute of my report model. Instead I get the following error

```
NoMethodError in ReportsController#show

undefined method `start_date' for #<Prawn::Document:0x007fdafbce6930>
```

So my start_date method is referring to my Document object instead of my Report object. How do I access the variables and methods of my report object from inside this block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual JavaScript trick should work:

```
def pdf_output
  report = self
  Prawn::Document.new do
    text "Start date: #{report.start_date.strftime('%e %b %Y').squish}"
  end
end
```

Just grab a reference to the `self` you need so that you don't have to worry about what Prawn is doing to `self` inside your block.

Comment: I was going to answer this, but I had that sneaking feeling that I was mixing up Ruby's `self` and Javascript's `this`... the two are so similar in some ways and so different in others. Mostly different I guess.

Comment: mu to the rescue, yet again. Thanks.